gps lati and long with/without dot
i am new here and i try to find help. I have a big database with 80000 gps records.
BUT ther are 10000 with dot (50.1234) and 70000 without the dot in the latitude and longtitude, like this 501234.
I have also a map with spartial search and i can also update the records via apex, there is also a updateproces when i change gps data so the location spartial data is updatet when i change the latitude or longtitude.
so now the spartial data (SDO_GEOMETRY) on the map is only viewing the data from the rows with dot.
How can i change this so all data are on the map? Sure i can update the rows manual, 70000 rows i take a lot time hehe.
This is the update process for the location data:
update sitetb_gps
set location = sdo_geometry(2001,4326,sdo_point_type(longtitude,latitude,null),null,null)
where latitude is not null and
longtitude is not null and
rowid = :P1061_ROWID;
commit;
How can i change this so all data are on the map? Sure i can update the rows manual, 70000 rows i take a lot time hehe.

How do you know if a longitude of 179000 is 17.9000 or 179.000?

yes its right they ar different in lengt i have only the option for limit the lenght, so a update process that calls only to numbers they have 5 numbers.  but how?

What does "update process that calls only to numbers they have 5 numbers" mean? Are you talking about 5 digits? Or numbers greater than 9999 (5 integer digits)? Or something else? It would be best if you [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data (and include rows of data representative of the different edge cases); an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you wish to implement; and the expected output for that sample data.

Something like:
UPDATE sitetb_gps
SET latitude  = CASE
                WHEN latitude <= -90 or latitude > 90
                THEN latitude / 10000
                ELSE latitude
                END,
    longitude = CASE
                WHEN longitude <= -180 or longitude > 180
                THEN longitude / 10000
                ELSE longitude
                END,
    location  = SDO_GEOMETRY(
                  2001,
                  4326,
                  SDO_POINT_TYPE(
                    CASE
                    WHEN longitude <= -180 or longitude > 180
                    THEN longitude / 10000
                    ELSE longitude
                    END,
                    CASE
                    WHEN latitude <= -90 or latitude > 90
                    THEN latitude / 10000
                    ELSE latitude
                    END,
                    NULL
                  ),
                  NULL,
                  NULL
                )
WHERE  ((latitude <= -90 OR latitude > 90) AND longitude IS NOT NULL)
OR     ((longtitude <= -180 OR longitude > 180) AND latitude IS NOT NULL);

Assuming that your values are always out by a multiple of 10000 if they are outside the normal bounds.
Once you fix your data, add constraints to your table to prevent people from inserting values that are too large.
ALTER TABLE sitetb_gps
  ADD CONSTRAINT sitetb_gps__latitude__chk
  CHECK (latitude IS NULL OR (-90 < latitude AND latitude <= 90));

ALTER TABLE sitetb_gps
  ADD CONSTRAINT sitetb_gps__longitude__chk
  CHECK (longitude IS NULL OR (-180 < longitude AND longitude <= 180));

(And you can also change the data type to for the latitude column to NUMBER(6,4) and longitude to NUMBER(7,4).)
